# I'm getting a query error when adding paginate to my livewire component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

My component lists user teams within a radius of an (friendly) event. I added the ability to search by team name. This all works fine until I try to add paginate.

This is the error I get after adding `->paginate($this->perPage)`

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' 
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `teams` where `users`.`id` = `teams`.`user_id` 
and `division` = 12U and `name` like %%)
```

Her is my Livewire component:

```
class ListAreaTeams extends Component
{

    use WithPagination;

    public $friendly;

    public $searchTeam = '';
    public $perPage = 5;
    

    public function render()
    {
        // Get friendly
        $friendly = $this->friendly;

        $users = User::query()->whereHas('teams', function($q) use ($friendly){
                        $q->where('division', $friendly->division)
                        ->searchTeam($this->searchTeam)
                        ->paginate($this->perPage);
                    })
                    ->where('id', '!=', $friendly->user_id)
                    ->distance($friendly->latitude, $friendly->longitude);
                    
            return view('livewire.list-area-teams', [
                'users'=> $users
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: the `whereHas` is for constraining the result set, it isn't for returning results itself so calling `paginate` doesn't make sense there as its not the actual query returning a result

Answer (score 0):

@lagbox thanks for the hint. I was able to fix this by using a foreach on the users->teams. Not very pretty but it does the job.

```
class ListAreaTeams extends Component
{

    use WithPagination;

    public $friendly;

    public $searchTeam = '';
    public $perPage = 10;
    

    public function render()
    {
        
        $friendly = $this->friendly;

        $users = User::with('teams')
            ->where('onboard_completed', 1)
            ->where('id', '!=', $friendly->user_id)
            ->distance($friendly->latitude, $friendly->longitude);
        
        $teams = [];
        foreach($users as $user) {
            foreach($user->teams as $team) {
                $teams[] = $team;
            }
        }
        $teams = $team
                ->where('division', $friendly->division)
                ->searchTeam($this->searchTeam)
                ->paginate($this->perPage);

        return view('livewire.list-area-teams', [
            'teams'=> $teams
        ]);
    }
}
```